# Where is the PivotTable in MDX debugger

Tags: debugging, ssas-2012

[I am reading an article](http://cwebbbi.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/using-the-mdx-script-debugger-in-bids/)
I am using SQL Server 2012 Datatools.
I hit F10 to start debugging MDX code in Calculations.
The cursor highlighted the first statement, Calculate.
But I don't see the Pivot Table tab. I only see the MDX1, MDX2, MDX3 and MDX4 tabs.

Where I can find a browser control?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this has been removed. Which in my opinion is not good.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143682.aspx

Behavior Changes in SQL Server 2012

---

This section documents the behavioral changes reported for SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services (SSAS) features in SQL Server 2012.

Analysis Services, Multidimensional Mode

Cube browser in Management Studio and Cube Designer has been removed

The cube browser control that let you drag and drop fields onto a PivotTable structure in Management Studio or in Cube Designer has been removed from the product. The control was an Office Web Control (OWC) component. OWC was deprecated by Office and is no longer available.